# How to format a Date field in Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a `stringVariable` coming from the backend service that I have converted into a Date field like below.

```
date d = new Date(stringVariable );
```

This worked fine. However the new date output looks like this.

```
Thu Jun 29 2017 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

I need it to be changes to a different format `yyyy-mm-dd` and i would need the variable 'd' to remain as a Date not a String.

If I use date pipe transform method or `.toLocaleString`, it will convert the final output 'd' to a string. That shouldn't happen.

Appreciate help from experts.

Comment: Where will the date output be used/shown? On your component.html?

Comment: did you  consider to use moment.js ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the format of the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

However, in order to solve your problem, you can use date pipe on your template/html. It is natively available in Angular. It will not mutate the value of `d`, as it merely transform it into your required `yyyy-mm-dd` format. The value of `d` on your component.ts will still be in the Date Object format, thus you can continue to use it on other parts of your component. You can check out the accepted formats for the date pipe over [here](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe).

```
<input [ngModel]="d  | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"/>
```

You may refer to this [short demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-pipe-example-p9j46e?file=src/app/app.component.html).

---

EDIT: Since you are using PrimeNg's p-calendar component, we can simply make use of the [dateFormat](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar) property which serves the same purpose as the pipe above.

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="d" dateFormat="yy-MM-dd"></p-calendar>
```

Here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/prime-ng-calendar-o34xwq?file=app%2Fcalendar%2Fcalendar.component.html). On my demo, I have binded the `onSelect` event such that it prints the updated `d` everytime you select a new date.

Comment: This solution looks simple. I cant get it to working though.

Comment: I have done the below changes as per your suggestion

<p-calender  [(ngModel)]="d | date:''yyyy-mm-dd"></p-calnder>

However it complains that, the pipe could not be found

Comment: @Seb I see. I didn't know. Ok, now I see the full picture. Give me a second, let me make some modifications.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. One last doubt in this regard.

What if I want to display the date field in a for loop together with other fields

<td *ngFor="let col of columns" align="center" >
<span>col.field</span>
</td>

and one col.field is the date field and the are other string fields as well. I tried with *ngIf statement, but I couldnt get it to work

Comment: @Seb glad to help! Hmm.. What do you mean by that? What exactly is not working?